# paypal python package not working, all tests returns error code -1

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Here is what i do and the paypal-python git repo is https://github.com/duointeractive/paypal-python

create a virtual env
pip install paypal
pip install nose

in site-packages/paypal directory, copy the tests directory into it.

cp api_details_blank.py api_details.py

fill with my api_user_name, password, signature and a customer's credit account info

nosetests tests/

after doing that, all i got is

```
...EEE.E...
======================================================================
ERROR: test_abbreviated_sale (paypal.tests.test_direct_payment.TestDirectPayment)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/tests/test_direct_payment.py", line 51, in test_abbreviated_sale
    sale = interface.do_direct_payment(**self.credit_card)
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/interface.py", line 270, in do_direct_payment
    return self._call('DoDirectPayment', **kwargs)
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/interface.py", line 125, in _call
    raise PayPalAPIResponseError(response)
PayPalAPIResponseError: None (Error Code: -1)


ERROR: test_authorize_and_delayed_capture (paypal.tests.test_direct_payment.TestDirectPayment)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/tests/test_direct_payment.py", line 61, in test_authorize_and_delayed_capture
    auth = interface.do_direct_payment('Authorization', **self.credit_card)
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/interface.py", line 270, in do_direct_payment
    return self._call('DoDirectPayment', **kwargs)
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/interface.py", line 125, in _call
    raise PayPalAPIResponseError(response)
PayPalAPIResponseError: None (Error Code: -1)

======================================================================
ERROR: test_authorize_and_void (paypal.tests.test_direct_payment.TestDirectPayment)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/tests/test_direct_payment.py", line 74, in test_authorize_and_void
    auth = interface.do_direct_payment('Authorization', **self.credit_card)
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/interface.py", line 270, in do_direct_payment
    return self._call('DoDirectPayment', **kwargs)
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/interface.py", line 125, in _call
    raise PayPalAPIResponseError(response)
PayPalAPIResponseError: None (Error Code: -1)

======================================================================
ERROR: test_sale (paypal.tests.test_direct_payment.TestDirectPayment)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/tests/test_direct_payment.py", line 30, in test_sale
    sale = interface.do_direct_payment('Sale', **self.credit_card)
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/interface.py", line 270, in do_direct_payment
    return self._call('DoDirectPayment', **kwargs)
  File "/Users/binleixue/Envs/tradeplatform/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/interface.py", line 125, in _call
    raise PayPalAPIResponseError(response)
PayPalAPIResponseError: None (Error Code: -1)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 23.885s

FAILED (errors=4)
```

**does anybody know how to deal with that?**

Answer (score 0):

If you're still stuck I created [PayLib](https://github.com/rutherford/PayLib) as a simple abstraction above PayPal Express Checkout for recurring payments. Sample code in the readme and it's up on PyPI too.

Comment: No problem. If you find it useful, could you mark this as the answer? Thanks!